# Angular 2 CSS order of precedence not respected

Tags: css, angular, webpack

On my layout page, in the `<head>`, I have the following styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/vendor.css">
<style>
    .bg-dark {
        background-color: #240000; 
    }
</style>
```

I have added the link to my layout page. The `style` block is added dynamically by Angular & webpack. From what I know about CSS, that last `.bg-dark` class should win over any `.bg-dark` class declared in `vendor.css. Yet I see the following:

[image: Incorrect order of precedence]

Is this something caused by the magical pre-rendering of Angular? Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: !important Always wins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `background-color` attribute in vendor.css has the `!important` flag, which elevates its priority:

```css
background-color: #222222 !important;
```

To override that setting, you should set the `!important` flag in your layout page CSS:

```
<style>
    .bg-dark {
        background-color: #240000 !important; 
    }
</style>
```

or remove that flag in vendor.css, if your can.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that.